# NSIS play with InstalldirRegKey

Tags: build, installation, nsis, instructions

From NSIS documentation, we have

> `root_key subkey key_name`   This attribute tells the installer to
>   check a string in the registry, and use it for the install dir if that
>   string is valid. If this attribute is present, it will override the
>   InstallDir attribute if the registry key is valid, otherwise it will
>   fall back to the InstallDir default.

So, if I have these lines in a `.nsi` file:

```
InstallDir "D:\myFolder\myFile"

InstallDirRegKey HKCU "Software\${PRODUCT_COMPANY}\${PRODUCT_NAME}" "Install_Dir"
```

I understand that I set my install directory to `D:\myFolder\myFile` as default directory, but if `Software\${PRODUCT_COMPANY}\${PRODUCT_NAME}` is a valid path, then I will use it instead. Is that correct?

From another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896463/nsis-silent-install-started-via-code?rq=1), I understand that the `InstallDirRegKey` instruction is used to overwrite previous installation at same location. How is it working more precisely? If I have the following,

```
InstallDir "D:\myFolder\myFile"

InstallDirRegKey HKCU "D:\myFolder\myFile" "Install_Dir"
```

will a new `.exe` file generated by the NSIS script overwrite the previous one? Or does it mean that the executable will overwrite the previous one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

InstallDirRegKey only reads from the registry, it never writes.

Before your `.onInit` is executed NSIS does:

1. If `InstallDir` is set, that path is copied to `$Instdir`
2. If `InstallDirRegKey`  is set and the registry key exists, the path from the registry (With the filename removed) is copied to `$Instdir`

So if you want InstallDirRegKey to have any effect the next time a user runs the installer you must point it to a key that your installer creates in one of your sections. It can be the UninstallString command in your uninstall key or a application specific key like `HKLM\Software\My Company\My App`.

The whole point of this is that when the user re-installs or installs a new version of your app it will be installed in the same folder (overwriting/upgrading the existing install).