# Which variable holds the previous installation path? NSIS

Tags: nsis

I would like to know which variable holds the installation previously selected installation path. How do I set to "C:\Users\Admin\Document\" as default installation path.[Image shows the previous Installation path.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r25L0.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSIS play with InstalldirRegKey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441640/nsis-play-with-installdirregkey)

Answer (score 2):

There is no variable that holds the previous install directory.

If you are using the `InstallDirRegKey` attribute (or the MUI defines that are associated with it) then `$InstDir` will be set to the path found in the registry when the installer starts. You are responsible for writing this registry value during installation, NSIS will only read it.